# How does hexadecimal to %x work?

Tags: c

I am learning in C and I got a question regarding this conversion.

```
short int x = -0x52ea;

printf ( "%x", x );
```

output:

```
ffffad16
```

I would like to know how this conversion works because it's supposed to be on a test and we won't be able to use any compilers. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to know how this conversion works

It is *undefined behavior* (UB)

---

```
short int x = -0x52ea;
```

1. `0x52ea` is a *hexadecimal constant*.  It has the value of 52EA<sub>16</sub>, or 21,226<sub>10</sub>. It has type `int` as it fits in an `int`, even if `int` was 16 bit.   OP's `int` is evidently 32-bit.
2. `-` negates the value to -21,226.
3. The value is assigned to a `short int` which can encode -21,226, so no special issues with assigning this `int` to a `short int`.

---

```
printf("%x", x );
```

4. `short int x` is passed to a `...` function, so goes through the *default argument
   promotions* and becomes an `int`.  So an `int` with the value -21,226 is passed.
5. `"%x"` used with `printf()`, expects an `unsigned` argument.   Since the type passed is not an `unsigned` (and not an `int` with a non-negative value - See exception C11dr §6.5.2.2 6), the result is *undefined behavior* (UB).  Apparently the UB on your machine was to print the hex pattern of a 32-bit [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) of -21,226 or `FFFFAD16`.

If the exam result is anything but UB, just smile and nod and realize the curriculum needs updating.

Comment: There is no evidence that it's 32-bits, there's an implicit conversion when calling `printf()`. `(char)(-1)` will cause similar effect.

Comment: @Havenard OP's output is `ffffad16`, which would be a typical response with 32-bit `int` and this code's UB.  Yet ever diminishing value explaining UB.

Comment: Yes but because `printf()` is a variadic function, all integer types are implicitly promoted to `long` unless they are 64-bit, just as `float` is promoted to `double`.

Comment: @Havenard "all integer types are implicitly [promoted to long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901436/how-does-hexadecimal-to-x-work/46901686#comment80750619_46901686)" is not supported by the spec's §6.3.1.1 2 which outlines integer promotion to `int/unsigned`.

Comment: @Havenard `(char)(-1)` would have a similar effect if `char` was signed.  With `char` as unsigned, `printf("%x", (char)(-1) );` may print `"ff"`.

Comment: Yes because unsigned char `ff` is positive, and when converted to `long` doesn't require any extra bits to be represented.

Comment: @Havenard There is not conversion to `long`.

Comment: I'm 100% positive there it, look it up.

Comment: @Havenard I did and gave you the [citation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901436/how-does-hexadecimal-to-x-work/46901686#comment80750698_46901686): "If an int can represent all values of the original type ..., the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned 
int`. These are called the integer promotions."  Should you disagree, recommend you post your reference.

Comment: So you just read they are implicitly promoted, what are you still missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157331/discussion-between-chux-and-havenard).

Answer (score 0):

The point here is that when a number is negative, it's structured in a completely different way.

1 in 16-bit hexadecimal is `0001`, -1 is `ffff`. The most relevant bit (`8000`) indicates that it's a negative number (admitting it's a signed integer), and that's why it can only go as positive as 32767 (`7fff`), and as negative as -32768 (`8000`).

Basically to transform from positive to negative, you invert all bits and sum 1. `0001` inverted is `fffe`, +1 = `ffff`.

This is a convention called [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) and it's used because it's quite trivial to do arithmetic using bitwise operations when you use it.

Comment: And your answer is correct only if the compiler implementers used two's complement arithmetic.  But that is likely the case, since most processors actually make that the easiest choice. It's just not always the case.